# Database value as "selected" item in html select dropdown list

Tags: html.dropdownlistfor

When adding a new record to my database I use an html select dropdown list to limit the user's choices for a particular field to: New, Good, Fair and Poor.  One of these four values will always get stored in that field.

On another page I give the user a chance to edit the content of that field.  There, I will also limit the user's choices to the same four values using the same html select dropdown list.

In order to maintain the current value as the default, I need it to be the "selected" value in my dropdown list.  How can I force the current value in the database to be the "selected" value in my dropdown list?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (Keep in mind I don't know how you're getting the value from the database, so adjust accordingly):

```
<?php $rating = value_from_db; ?> // However it is being passed.

<select name="rating">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="new" <?php ($rating == "new" ? "selected":"") ?> >New</option>
  <option value="good" <?php ($rating == "good" ? "selected":"") ?> >Good</option>
  <option value="fair" <?php ($rating == "fair" ? "selected":"") ?> >Fair</option>
  <option value="poor" <?php ($rating == "poor" ? "selected":"") ?> >Poor</option>
</select>
```

This uses the `Ternary Operation ?` for in-line `If/Else` statements to set the property to checked if the value from the DB matches the value from the option.

**Note** Also assuming you're using Php. No tags or indications otherwise, but I am doing a lot of assuming for this question...

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is a terrific idea.  I'm using Java inside a JSP file but the concept is the same and I am working to implement your suggestion.  Thank you!

Comment: Cool, the operator is essentially the same, the syntax will be slightly different between the two though. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may be interested, here is the final solution which works great!

```
<select name="condition">
  <option value="good" ${"good" == usedEquipListItem.condition ? "selected" : "" }>Good</option>
  <option value="fair" ${"fair" == usedEquipListItem.condition ? "selected" : "" }>Fair</option>
  <option value="poor" ${"poor" == usedEquipListItem.condition ? "selected" : "" }>Poor</option>
</select>
```

The variable usedEquipListItem.condition hold the current value from the database.